# Presto: How to assign dynamic aliases?

Tags: pivot, presto

I have a table that I want to pivot, however the "key" is dynamic:

| date | name | metric |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8/1 | foo | 0.1 |
| 8/2 | foo | 0.2 |
| 8/3 | foo | 0.3 |
| 8/5 | foo | 0.5 |
| 8/1 | bar | 0.1 |
| 8/2 | bar | 0.2 |
| 8/3 | bar | 0.3 |
| 8/5 | bar | 0.5 |

And I want to show the last 2 available dates as columns

| name | 8/3 | 8/5 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 0.3 | 0.5 |
| bar | 0.3 | 0.5 |

Is this possible?

Something like this doesn't work because it expects static keys:

```
SELECT
  uid,
  kv['c1'] AS c1,
  kv['c2'] AS c2,
  kv['c3'] AS c3
FROM (
  SELECT uid, map_agg(key, value) kv
  FROM vtable
  GROUP BY uid
) t
```

Answer (score -1):

if you don't mind having date value as column name , you can do this :

```sql
select name
     ,max(case when rn = 1 then metric end) LastMEtric
     ,max(case when rn = 2 then metric end) OneBeforeLastMetric
from (
   select * , row_number() over (partition by name order by date desc) rn
   from table
) t 
group by name
```